# Create PHP threads from HTTP request

Tags: php, multithreading, http, httprequest

I'm currently working on an apparently simple problem but i couldn't find the solution.

What I need to do is to start a thread in PHP (for example purpose it can just echo something) whenever an HTTP request is performed (it may be GET or POST). I should be able to kill the thread by performing another HTTP request.
I am currently working on Linux, more specific on a raspberry PI 3 running Raspbian 9 Stretch.

I thought about Docker but I couldn't find any reliable tutorial.
Any suggestions about it?

Comment: What's the relation to Docker? What have you tried? PHP has a builtin web server, have you tried that? Why do you need a thread (YX question)?

Comment: I previously checked docker and I thought form the beginning about it, however I can't find anything about how to use it from PHP (I'm asking here because I don't even know if it is possible).
I need multi-threading because I need different sessions from different accounts to be controlled and execute some code, but I don't want to just start developing the software but I prefer make a sample.

Comment: From manual context switching, over threads, processes to VMs, any of those could be used to solve the problem you describe. Which brings me to the description of your problem: There is none. Even the example purpose "just echo something" isn't really helpful, because that's a one-off task for which you don't need concurrency.